# Getting .mp4 from .f4m stream url

Tags: url, ffmpeg, streaming, mp4

Currently I have the following url 
http://vpl.rtl.be/z//2018/08/21/CA00001318626_,400,600,800,1200,1800,.mp4.csmil/manifest.f4m?hdcore=1

which contains an .f4m file, which directs to an mp4 file.

I can't find a way to get that mp4 from that file (i just need the direct mp4 url or file).

How should I proceed? I have tried using ffmpeg or simply reading the file, with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much familiar with FFMpeg but you can try [livestreamer](https://www.videohelp.com/software/livestreamer) :-)

Command line:

```
livestreamer "hds://http://vpl.rtl.be/z//2018/08/21/CA00001318626_,400,600,800,1200,1800,.mp4.csmil/manifest.f4m?hdcore=1" best -o video.ts
```

I tried in .mp4 format but it didn't like that, the file header shows FLV, you can use [VLC Media Player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) to open the **video.ts** file.

Good luck!

[image]